# Weird answer to "What is the smallest number *n* by which the given number *x* must be divided to make it into a perfect square?"

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

I came across the following question: What is the smallest number n by which the given number x must be divided to make it into a perfect square?

n = find_number ( x )

I know the standard way to do this to find the prime factors of x and multiple by what is necessary to have perfect squares in the prime factors, but I saw this answer:

The number is 1/x so x/1/x= x^2

Not sure if that it completely wrong, or is a genius and direct solution

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm . . . .1/(4*x) would appear to be smaller than 1/x, at least for x > 1.

Comment: Try testing it with `x=0`...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This should be asked at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Completely wrong -- 1/(y^2 x) is even smaller for all y > 0, and there is no lower bound.

Comment: I think "number" should be defined in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no thats not correct ...

for 2 you say its 1/2 then 2 / (1/2) is 4 which is perfect square cool

but what about 1/8 then 2 /(1/8) is 16 which is perfect square

and 1/8 < 1/2 so thats one contradiction you need to know that thats not correct